# Enable the radio list using the first checkbox

Tags: javascript, php

the radio listed are disabled, now i want to enable them when the checkbox is checked, and will be disabled when unchecked.

```
 <p>1.0 Educational Qualification</p>
 <p><input type="checkbox" id="chk" name="chk"/>1.1 Highest relevant academic degree or educational attainment</p>
 <p><input type="radio" name="educationalqualification" disabled="true"/>Doctorate</p>
 <p><input type="radio" name="educationalqualification" disabled="true"/>Master's Degree</p>
 <p><input type="radio" name="educationalqualification" disabled="true"/>LLB and MD</p>
 <p><input type="radio" name="educationalqualification" disabled="true"/>Diploma Course (Above Bachelor's Degree)</p>
 <p><input type="radio" name="educationalqualification" disabled="true"/>Bachelor's Degree</p>

</body>
```

Comment: What's wrong with all the ways that Google found?

Comment: lots of them out there: http://goo.gl/zgQjL0

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
        {
            $("input[type='radio']").prop("disabled",false);
        }
        else
        {
            $("input[type='radio']").prop("disabled",true);
                    $("input[type='radio']").prop("checked",false);
        }
    });
 });
 </script>
```

SEE **[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/satishJS/x9NGL/)**

Comment: thanks, but is there a possible way if the checkbox is checked, the radio button will be cleared?

Comment: radio button will be cleared means? please explain more?

Comment: when the i unchecked the checkbox, the radio button list will be disabled but the radio button that i selected is still selected even though it is disabled. it should be deselect when i uncheck the checkbox.

Comment: `$("input[type='radio']").prop("checked",false);` append this line in else condition

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#chk').click(function () {
           if($(this).prop('checked')){
             $('input[name=educationalqualification]').attr("disabled",false);
           }
           else {
             $('input[name=educationalqualification]').attr("disabled",true);  
           }
    });
  });
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a6NJk/678/)

Answer (score 1):

And Vanilla:

```
function toggle(checked) {
    var names = document.getElementsByName("educationalqualification");

    for (var i = 0; i <= names.length - 1; i++) {
        names[i].disabled = !checked;
        names[i].checked = false;
    }
}

var check = document.getElementById("chk");
check.addEventListener("click", function () {
    toggle(this.checked)
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/78NNx/4/)**

Comment: thanks, but is there a possible way if the checkbox is checked, the radio button will be cleared?